# Use strict belongs to with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Suppose we have the following models:

```
class A < AR
    has_many :bs

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bs
end

class B < AR
    belongs_to :a
end
```

And we create new A object with nested forms in this way:

```
class AsController < AC
    def create
        a = A.create(a_params)
    end

    ...
    def a_params
        params.require(:a).permit(bs_attributes: [...])
    end
end
```

This generates an error something like `b.a must be exists`. It means that `b.a_id` can't be nil or `a` must be previously created.

All are saying the solution is `optional: true` for the belongs_to association.

But what happens when the association is really strict and `b.a` can't never be nil?

Is a good solution put `optional: true` and add validation rules on B?

Answer (score 0):

Often times we want to validate that something with a `belongs_to` relationship has that column set.

For instance, if we have posts that belong to discussions then likely want to make sure that every post belongs to a discussion and its `discussion_id` is set. Validating this is the default behavior in rails 5.

In Rails 4 we had to add something like this...

```
class Post
  belongs_to :discussion
  validates :discussion_id, presence: true
end
```

However, setting `belongs_to :discussion, optional: true` in Rails 5 will take that validation away. I would only do this if I want to allow posts to exist that are not associated with a discussion.

If you want the relationship of `A has_many :bs` in your example to be strict then do not add `optional: true` and Rails 5 will validate this for you.

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

If you want to create A and new Bs all at once then you'll want to follow the pattern outlined in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

```
params = { a: {
  name: 'A new A!', bs_attributes: [
    { title: 'Something new b' },
    { title: 'Something else new b' }
  ]
}}


class AsController < AC
  def create
    a = A.create(a_params)
  end

    ...
  def a_params
    params.require(:a).permit(:name, bs_attributes: [...])
  end
end


a.bs.length # => 2
a.bs.first.title # => 'Something new b'
a.bs.second.title # => 'Something else new b'
```

Comment: If you are using nested forms (using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`), object A can't be created because b.a can't be nil. The question is how to prevent this error without adding `optional: true` to the belongs_to association

Comment: I think you need to make the new A and B objects with `new` and then running `a.save` should save everything to the database.

Comment: According to the docs, you should not even need to do that. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html just make sure there are params for creating the new A object